# Response time for graphql subscriptions

Tags: reactjs, axios, graphql, aws-amplify, graphql-subscriptions

**What we have**

- Tech stack: React, AWS Amplify, Graphql.....
- We are developing an application which is using graphql subscriptions
  to get real-time data with AWS Amplify.

**What we want**

- Main requirement is to let user know if there is low network connection/high latency.
- See if subscriptions are taking too long to get data possibly due to low network connectivity
- This could be something like axios's request and response interceptors.

**Worth noting**

- Its not about online and offline events from the browser. User can stay connected even with very low network connectivity. We actually want to check if there is high latency
- Ping after every N mins or downloading some resource from server is not a good idea. Need something else.